# Sublime Text 3 Doesn't Recognize %i in ruby

Tags: ruby, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using the latest build of Sublime Text 3. When typing `%i[foo bar]` Sublime does not seem to recognize this and I don't get the proper highlighting.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, is there a way I can fix this on my end or is this something that Sublime HQ would have to fix?

[image]

Comment: You might know, but just to make sure; the `%i` literal notation was introduced in Ruby 2.0, so it is new. Any versions of IDE published earlier than that would not be compatible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `%i[foo bar] # [:foo :bar]` literal notation for a symbol array was only [implemented](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/91bd6e711db3418baa287e936d4b0fac99927711) in Ruby 2.0, while the Ruby language definition that ships with ST3 is mostly focused on 1.9 and earlier. I searched around a bit, but unfortunately I couldn't find any `.tmLanguage` files that are updated for 2.0, let alone include this literal notation, so I can't point you to a ready-made solution. But, I do have a few suggestions.

First, head over to the unofficial [Sublime Text Issues tracker](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues) and post a bug report. We're not sure how much attention is paid to this list by the developer, but it at least broadens the issue's visibility and may prompt someone to post a fix. You can also reply to [this thread](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14387) on the Sublime Text forum and perhaps reference your issue.

The second option, if you have good regex-fu, is to hack the `Ruby.tmLanguage` file and add support yourself. I was going to post directions on how to do it, but then I tried it myself and it seemed to work, so feel free to use my work:

1. Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages` to open up the `Packages` folder in your system's file explorer.
2. Create a folder called `Ruby2`.
3. Copy the contents of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/7757336) into a new file, and save it in your `Ruby2` directory as `Ruby2.tmLanguage`.
4. Restart Sublime, switch to your problematic code, and select `View -> Syntax -> Ruby2`. Both lines should now be highlighted the same way. Here's a before and after screenshot using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme):

[image: Ruby literal before and after]

I hope this helps. I'm not a Rubyist, so if I made any blatant errors please let me know.

From my (brief) research there definitely seems to be a need for an updated version of `Ruby.tmLanguage` for all the new features in 2.0, so hopefully any issues you post will prompt someone to start/publish a project. I've already done [something similar](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Python%20Improved) for Python, but my Ruby skillz just aren't there for this project :)

Good luck!

Comment: what about symbols and keywords, currently with `public: true, foo: bar`, "public" is highlighted differently then the rest of the hash keys.